# Apache config read header value

Tags: apache, header

Is there a way to read the value of a request header in Apache config? I want to avoid going into the .htaccess file and even better if I could avoid using SetEnvIf. 
I'm trying to implement the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1850482/138228

I can't really find much on this topic outside of using regex. What I'm looking for is something like :

> Header set NAME = %{value_of_different_header}%

Answer (score 3):

Reading answer from : https://serverfault.com/questions/136428/header-set-access-control-allow-origin-not-working-with-mod-rewrite-mod-jk

It seems the solution is:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(domaine1\.com|domain2\.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
```

But this has nothing to do with .htaccess, you can put such lines in regular apache configuration file (virtualhost?) without using the *bad* .htaccess dynamic configuration files.

The value part of the Header instruction is:

> value may be a character string, a string containing format specifiers or a combination of both

But the only format specifiers available are `%%` (for `%`), `%t` for a timestamp, `%D` (idem), `%{foo}e` and `%{foo}s` for environments variables.

`SetenvIf` is a good apache tool to read a request header, here reading the Origin header. Then, using environment variables is the classical way of writing complex things in Apache (I mean the way to store some sort of variables).

So I don't know why you would like another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a away of doing this without SetEnvIf but other than that just copying a different header can be done with the following, I was doing this as part of a ReverseProxy (hence using RequestHeader instead of Header) but the two appear to be interchangeable

```
###This reads the value of OldHeader into TempValue
SetEnvIf OldHeader ".+" TempValue=$0

###This will overwrite the value of "NewHeader" if it was already set
RequestHeader set NewHeader %{TempValue}e env=TempValue

###Optionally remove the original
RequestHeader unset OldHeader
```